# Coloring only the inside of a shape

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

Lets say that you are given this image

[image: Circle]

and are given the instruction to programmatically color only the inside of it the appropriate color, but the program would have to not only work on this shape and other primitives but on any outlined shape, however complex it may be and shaded or not.

This is the problem I am trying to solve, but here's where I'm stuck, it seems like it should be simple to teach a computer to see black lines, and color inside them. But searching mostly turns up eigenface style recognition algorithms, which seems to me to be over fitting and far greater complexity than is needed for at least the basic form of this problem.

I would like to frame this as a supervised learning classifier problem, the purpose of which is to feed my model a complete image and it will output smaller `numpy` arrays consisting of pixels classsified as `object`  or `background`. But in order to do that I would need to give it training data, which to me seems like I would need to hand label every pixel in my training set, which obviously defeats the purpose of the program.

Now that you have the background, here's my question, given this image, is there an efficient way to get two distinct arrays, each consisting of all adjacent pixels that do not contain any solid black (RGB(0,0,0)) pixels?

Which would make one set all pixels on the inside of the circle, and the other, all pixels on the outside of the circle

Comment: Yeah, it does seem simple to teach a computer to color inside of black lines, I don't see why you can't just start in the corner and walk through every pixel on the outside of the shape (and use backtracking to avoid the lines), which would give you your outside array, then just fill in the other pixels that aren't black. Am I missing something about the problem that makes it more complex?

Comment: That doesn't account for multiple shapes or, for example, shapes within shapes, I did consider that possibility though

Comment: what data exactly do you have? `it seems like it should be simple to teach a computer to see black lines` that's easy for humans, yes, but notoriously hard for computers. However, if the shapes you are trying to color are isoslated like the circle it's not that hard. If, on the hard, the shape is in a general image it is not that simple.

Comment: @KevinWells' solution works just fine for multiple shapes, and you haven't  explained what the intended result for shapes within shapes is anyway

Comment: Would you be open to using OpenCV module (cv2)?

Comment: @ChuckFulminata Why would that not work for multiple shapes? You will still end up with all of the pointsthat are inside of a black line, so as long as you check for multiple areas it should work fine. And you didn't mention having shapes within shapes, what would you want to have happen in that case? If you add complexity to the problem then of course you will add complexity to the solution

Comment: @KevinWells, Ok, perhaps I misunderstood you, could you perhaps put it in an answer and add some pseodo code to clarify?

Comment: @svs, Yes, I am aware that this is actually far harder than it seems like it "should be" I'm not delusional on that part, but I don't expect it to be easy, I expect it to be simple, as in, efficient and scalable, not a problem that has to be approached and optimized for image by image

Comment: @Divakar I would prefer to do it in pure python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) to do all the heavy lifting for you:

```
import scipy.ndimage
import scipy.misc

data = scipy.misc.imread(...)
assert data.ndim == 2, "Image must be monochromatic"

# finds and number all disjoint white regions of the image
is_white = data > 128
labels, n = scipy.ndimage.measurements.label(is_white)

# get a set of all the region ids which are on the edge - we should not fill these
on_border = set(labels[:,0]) | set(labels[:,-1]) | set(labels[0,:]) | set(labels[-1,:])

for label in range(1, n+1):  # label 0 is all the black pixels
    if label not in on_border:
        # turn every pixel with that label to black
        data[labels == label] = 0
```

This will fill all closed shapes within the image, considering a shape cut by the edge of the image not to be closed

Comment: when run the line `on_border` returns the error, `unhashable type numpy.array` and I don't know why because this is the only line I'm not entirely clear on how it works

Comment: `data` needs to be 2D - it sounds like it is 3d for you

Comment: That line forms a list of all the region ids which fall on the edge - `labels[:,0]` is the first column of the image, etc. `set` is being used here to remove duplicates efficiently

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful