# Itereating over an image with backtracking

Tags: python, image, numpy, iteration

So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585243/coloring-only-the-inside-of-a-shape?noredirect=1#comment60802570_36585243) and in one of the comments someone suggested

> I don't see why you can't just start in the corner and walk through every pixel on the outside of the shape (and use backtracking to avoid the lines), which would give you your outside array, then just fill in the other pixels that aren't black.

But I don't understand how you would actually go about implementing said solution, because from my understanding, if I have an iterable

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I can iterate over it

```
for item in list:
    do something
```

I can even make it stop, start or anything else using conditionals, but I do not know how I could get it to iterate over the outer white pixels without also picking up the inner white pixels

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly You want to start in the corner of an image and set every pixel outside of any shape to `black`, lets give it a value `1`. So after this procedure You will have an array with inner pixels in every shape set to `white` or `0` and every outer or border pixel to `1`.

You didn't specify any details so I can give You only some pseudocode. You want to iterate over 2d array using recurention:

```
def fill(A, x, y):
    A[x][y] = 1
    if x-1 >= 0 and A[x-1][y] == 0:
        fill(A, x-1, y)
    if x+1 < N and A[x+1][y] == 0:
        fill(A, x+1, y)
    if y-1 >= 0 and A[x][y-1] == 0:
        fill(A, x-1, y-1)
    if y+1 < N and A[x][y+1] == 0:
        fill(A, x, y+1)

fill(A, 0, 0)
```

It's pretty easy solution and will work unless `0,0` is inside of a shape or belongs to shape border. You can use 2d `numpy.array` for `A` in Your implementation.

Comment: Parentheses are just clutter here

Comment: What details were you looking for?

Comment: @ChuckFulminata I meant example input, desired output format etc. so we could provide You more specific answer with complete implementation but I hope You will be able to produce it by yourself now.